# Sorting by ReceivedTime causing automation error

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to download a specific attachment from an outlook folder, and it works when I sort the mailbox in ascending order. When I sort it in descending order, I suddenly get an Automation Error.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Taxinfo()

Dim folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNS As Outlook.Namespace
Dim olfldr As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim sharedemail As Outlook.Recipient
Dim olMail As Variant
Dim myTasks As Outlook.Items
Dim itm As Outlook.MailItem
Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim y As Workbook
'Dim BodyText
Set y = Workbooks.Open("Current working spreadsheet here")
'Dim daysAgo As Long


Dim priorSaveFolder As Object
Set priorSaveFolder = y.Sheets("VBA Inputs").Range("B10") 'this is just the intended save location
'daysAgo = 3 'not currently being used

'Find Mailbox to search
Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set sharedemail = olNS.CreateRecipient("mailbox i'm using")
Set olfldr = olNS.GetSharedDefaultFolder(sharedemail, olFolderInbox)
Set folder = olfldr
Set myTasks = folder.Items
Set myTasks = folder.Items.Restrict("[Subject]='Email Subject'")
myTasks.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", False 
'if I change this to True, I get "Run-time error '440': Automation Error


For Each olMail In myTasks
    If olMail.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
        While olMail.Attachments.Count > 0
'This times out or doesn't work for some reason
'            For Each objAtt In olMail.Attachments
'                If InStr(objAtt.Filename, "MTTAX") Or InStr(objAtt.Filename, "mttax") Then
'                    olMail.Attachments(1).SaveAsFile priorSaveFolder & "MTTAX.html"
'                    Exit For
'                End If
'            Next objAtt
            If (Left$(olMail.Attachments(1).Filename, 5) = "mttax" Or Left$(olMail.Attachments(1).Filename, 5) = "MTTAX") Then
                olMail.Attachments(1).SaveAsFile priorSaveFolder & "MTTAX.html"
            End If
            If (Left$(olMail.Attachments(1).Filename, 5) = "mttax" Or Left$(olMail.Attachments(1).Filename, 5) = "MTTAX") Then
                Exit For
            End If
            If (Left$(olMail.Attachments(2).Filename, 5) = "mttax" Or Left$(olMail.Attachments(2).Filename, 5) = "MTTAX") Then
                olMail.Attachments(2).SaveAsFile priorSaveFolder & "MTTAX.html"
            End If
            If (Left$(olMail.Attachments(2).Filename, 5) = "mttax" Or Left$(olMail.Attachments(2).Filename, 5) = "MTTAX") Then
                Exit For
            End If
            If (Left$(olMail.Attachments(3).Filename, 5) = "mttax" Or Left$(olMail.Attachments(3).Filename, 5) = "MTTAX") Then
                olMail.Attachments(3).SaveAsFile priorSaveFolder & "MTTAX.html"
            End If
            If (Left$(olMail.Attachments(3).Filename, 5) = "mttax" Or Left$(olMail.Attachments(3).Filename, 5) = "MTTAX") Then
                Exit For
            End If
            If (Left$(olMail.Attachments(4).Filename, 5) = "mttax" Or Left$(olMail.Attachments(4).Filename, 5) = "MTTAX") Then
                olMail.Attachments(4).SaveAsFile priorSaveFolder & "MTTAX.html"
            End If
            If (Left$(olMail.Attachments(4).Filename, 5) = "mttax" Or Left$(olMail.Attachments(4).Filename, 5) = "MTTAX") Then
                Exit For
            End If
            If (Left$(olMail.Attachments(5).Filename, 5) = "mttax" Or Left$(olMail.Attachments(5).Filename, 5) = "MTTAX") Then
                olMail.Attachments(5).SaveAsFile priorSaveFolder & "MTTAX.html"
            End If
            If (Left$(olMail.Attachments(5).Filename, 5) = "mttax" Or Left$(olMail.Attachments(5).Filename, 5) = "MTTAX") Then
                Exit For
            End If
            If (Left$(olMail.Attachments(6).Filename, 5) = "mttax" Or Left$(olMail.Attachments(6).Filename, 5) = "MTTAX") Then
                olMail.Attachments(6).SaveAsFile priorSaveFolder & "MTTAX.html"
            End If
            If (Left$(olMail.Attachments(6).Filename, 5) = "mttax" Or Left$(olMail.Attachments(6).Filename, 5) = "MTTAX") Then
                Exit For
            End If
            If (Left$(olMail.Attachments(7).Filename, 5) = "mttax" Or Left$(olMail.Attachments(7).Filename, 5) = "MTTAX") Then
                olMail.Attachments(7).SaveAsFile priorSaveFolder & "MTTAX.html"
            End If
            If (Left$(olMail.Attachments(7).Filename, 5) = "mttax" Or Left$(olMail.Attachments(7).Filename, 5) = "MTTAX") Then
                Exit For
            End If
        Wend
    End If
Next olMail

Dim IE As InternetExplorer
Dim url As String

url = priorSaveFolder & "MTTAX.html"

Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate url
        Do Until .readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
    End With

    IE.ExecWB 17, 0 '// SelectAll
    IE.ExecWB 12, 2 '// Copy selection
    y.Sheets("Tax").Range("A1").PasteSpecial
    IE.Quit




End Sub
```

The code works perfectly when myTasks.sort "[ReceivedTime]", False, except it's pulling an attachment from an email from 2019. If I try to sort the other direction, then it errors out. How do I pull the most recent email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue ended up being in the script to filter through the attachments. Deleting those lines out and replacing them with the following solved my issue:

```
For Each olMail In myTasks
    If olMail.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
        For Each objAtt In olMail.Attachments
            If InStr(objAtt.Filename, "MTTAX") Or InStr(objAtt.Filename, "mttax") Then
                objAtt.SaveAsFile priorSaveFolder & "MTTAX.html"
                Exit For
            End If
        Next objAtt
    End If
Next olMail
```